# Unwanted multiple requests while using Connect/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, request, connect

I am trying to create middleware with Connect that displays Hello World to the webpage and also logs it in the console. I've been able to get it to work in my browswer but I noticed the console logs it twice - it doesn't do this when using curl. I don't have favicons and all extensions in Chrome are disabled.

Here is my code... rather simple:

```
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('hello world');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World');
});
app.listen(5000);
```

Again, after opening `http://localhost:5000` in Chrome, this is the output in the terminal:

`hello world`

`hello world`

Why is it being called twice? Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting two requests and most probably chrome checks for favicon. Add console.log(req); and check what requests are made to server.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log('hello world');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World');
});
```

Comment: console.log(req.url) is less verbose and should be easier to see exactly what the browser is requesting on the second request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When someone connects with server it is sent message on server.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's being called twice. I understand when someone connects to the server a request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

That's not normal. If you simply refresh browser's page (Ctrl + R), you must see "hello world" only once. Open *Developer Tools* in Chrome (menu button -> *Tools* -> *Developer Tools*) and switch to *Network* tab. Then refresh browser's page again and check the requests browser sends.

Answer (score -1):

From the docs:

response.end([data], [encoding])

This method signals to the server that all of the response headers and body have been sent; that server should consider this message complete. The method, response.end(), MUST be called on each response.

If **data is specified**, it is equivalent to calling response.write(data, encoding) followed by response.end().

The last line seems like the key to this. You're seeing your first console log then what's the equivalent of a response.write. Apologies for lack of formatting, I'm on my iPad.